# Environment Variable in 64 bit OS nor recognized without reboot

Tags: environment-variables, tomcat6, installshield

I have Installshiled script which define CATALINA_HOME as environment Variable initially. same script after that execute the batch file service.bat that is using CATALINA_HOME. this file when executed display the error CATALINA_HOME is not define define correctly. as this variable is defined as environmental VARIABLE and pointing Tomcat Directory Properly. I thing the system require reboot to recognize environment Variables.Is there any way to define Environment that work directly without reboot. I am using 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Recognized by what? Any program that starts after the installation is complete should probably see that environment variable as defined. But if you need it in something that's already running, such as the installer itself, you may have to convince it to refresh.

Comment: Yes Micheal that is the case. I am running Installer that create CATALINA_HOME then same installer need to use this Environment Variable. as you said i need to refresh this variable. How can i refresh this one.

Comment: For that use, you're better off just reusing the same variable or property you use to set the environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but the script that you're running loads the env variables once when you start it so you won't get any new env variables added during the runtime of the script.

And in your script, if you just execute the batch file, it will use the same out dated env variables the script started with.

What I do is run 'cmd /k service.bat' This starts a new shell (with the updated env variables) and runs the batch file and terminates afterwards.

You shouldn't need to reboot between your install.

Comment: I tried cmd /k but unfortunately it is not working for me. Any other suggestion please.. thanks

Comment: can you show me the command you're running, are you using LaunchAppAndWait? and when you say not working, do you mean the cmd doesn't even run? or it runs but the env variable is not there or that all you know is tha tthe service doesn't start. this method has alwasys worked for me so perhaps the error is happening elsewhere